# Are phantomjs binary artifacts hosted on some repository?

Tags: phantomjs

I would like to download phantomjs binary within a Gradle build script.

Where are they hosted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

They are only hosted on bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/

To use them with Gradle, the only option found to be working so far is to use the [gradle-download-task](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task) plugin. To implement caching, you can copy paste [this code](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task/issues/89).

Otherwise, another potential option is to declare a custom ivy dependency, but so far I haven't found a way to get it to work. The issue is that bitbucket redirects to an Amazon S3 location, and [the HEAD request that Gradle first issues to get the file size fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253755/gradle-failing-to-download-dependency-when-head-request-fails), probably because of a request signature problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is an official download repository for PhantomJS: https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/

Comment: Thanks ! Do you know of a canonical link on how to use Bitbucket as a repository in Gradle ?

Comment: Not familiar with Gradle, what is a canonical link for it ?

Comment: What I meant was whether you knew, off the top of your head, a link explaining how to use Bitbucket as a repository in Gradle or any other build system, without having to search for it. Thanks anyway !